# Missing Column in Google Sheets after a Query + Importrange call

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Very simple query + importrange however, I really do not know why column I is not imported. All columns from A-J are there except for Column I.

```
=query({importrange("1B1uV11esy4EmHbz1DE1ApyGP6QiSa27BoPI7IHJFXBA","Budget!A5:J");
        importrange("1PEI_zKRdX4Rsez-KBEmruDjJXcHxfcgWL9MwZsDqR4E","Budget!A5:J");
        importrange("1r_LBfypWPy-x7Cajbed3vfp9oW_P_yCT7hOD2kAZ0Ow","Budget!A5:J");
        importrange("1a5KuC7_zlfLJ498LHjgHPv6O1WHkoSwHGc1r2edodYA","Budget!A5:J");
        importrange("1J_wUlThjMjsEkGDj5tUOl_eaniAHkVaz4hZXGFkT3PU","Budget!A5:J");
        importrange("1DtcA8CsRk42cx4QRs4qfiPHDDFyUUeZCKqSFUhNcJhU","Budget!A5:J");
        importrange("1ELTPcXc5tJh7YUX96kZBqE-jQLy7mSqVgbpygbEMZVw","Budget!A5:J");
        importrange("10pG3ZuCozKeJyFWkEsM3_aGYWGXibok0_wx28FInDJI","Budget!A5:J");
        importrange("1i_WT0mQJyweuhv_ObpZRalL76dbxAl9YxilMvJGngTw","Budget!A5:J")},
       "Select * where Col2 is not NULL")
```

Can someone help me out on why this is happening?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: As @player0 mentioned, if we had a sample Spreadsheet it'd be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT({
 IMPORTRANGE("1B1uV11esy4EmHbz1DE1ApyGP6QiSa27BoPI7IHJFXBA", "Budget!A5:J");
 IMPORTRANGE("1PEI_zKRdX4Rsez-KBEmruDjJXcHxfcgWL9MwZsDqR4E", "Budget!A5:J");
 IMPORTRANGE("1r_LBfypWPy-x7Cajbed3vfp9oW_P_yCT7hOD2kAZ0Ow", "Budget!A5:J");
 IMPORTRANGE("1a5KuC7_zlfLJ498LHjgHPv6O1WHkoSwHGc1r2edodYA", "Budget!A5:J");
 IMPORTRANGE("1J_wUlThjMjsEkGDj5tUOl_eaniAHkVaz4hZXGFkT3PU", "Budget!A5:J");
 IMPORTRANGE("1DtcA8CsRk42cx4QRs4qfiPHDDFyUUeZCKqSFUhNcJhU", "Budget!A5:J");
 IMPORTRANGE("1ELTPcXc5tJh7YUX96kZBqE-jQLy7mSqVgbpygbEMZVw", "Budget!A5:J");
 IMPORTRANGE("10pG3ZuCozKeJyFWkEsM3_aGYWGXibok0_wx28FInDJI", "Budget!A5:J");
 IMPORTRANGE("1i_WT0mQJyweuhv_ObpZRalL76dbxAl9YxilMvJGngTw", "Budget!A5:J")}),
 "where Col2 is not null", 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It did show up, however, the filters i used no longer works.

Comment: @bltbersonda can you share a copy of your sheet?